# Как поменять порядок открытых окон через cli?

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Есть список окон упорядоченных по глубине расположения на мониторе:

`xprop -root | grep "NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING(WINDOW)"`

Как мне поменять в нем местами окна?

Сейчас я вызываю `wmctrl -a <window_id> -i` для всех окон, чтобы получить желанный порядок.

Comment: А как вы предлагаете работать со стеком? Фокус на любое окно — `pop`, циклическое вращение — `pop_first && push_last` или `pop_last && push_first`. Также смотрите: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257320/how-to-define-window-stacking-order

Comment: pop_last && push_first. Спасибо за ссылку, я не удовлетворен ответом, но принимаю его.